# Why is PdfFontFactory unable to register Local Language Fonts located in app persistent data path in my unity android game?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, pdf-generation, itext7, truetype

I am using Itext7 to create pdf in my local language. Everything works fine on standalone_windows but in android the PdfFontFactory is not able to register those fonts.

**In Standalone_Windows** **I fetch raw files from streaming assets** and they work perfectly.

**In Android, I am downloading the fonts from streaming assets path to persistent data path using UnityWebRequest**

**This is the code for downloading and writing font bytes from streaming assets to persistent data path:**

```
 string fontpath1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "LEOPALMHINDI15K710.TTF");
    string fontpath2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "LEOPALMHINDI14K240.TTF");

    //Request Hindi Font 1

    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(fontpath1);
    request.SendWebRequest();
    while (!request.isDone)
    {


    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath , "LEOPALMHINDI15K710.TTF"),request.downloadHandler.data); 
    request.Dispose();
    //Request Hindi Font 2

    UnityWebRequest font2 = UnityWebRequest.Get(fontpath2);
    font2.SendWebRequest();
    while (!font2.isDone)
    {
       

    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "LEOPALMHINDI14K240.TTF"), font2.downloadHandler.data);
    font2.Dispose();
```

**This is the code I am using to read font files using filePath strings:**

```
    string HFOnt = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "LEOPALMHINDI15K710.TTF");
    string HFOnt2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "LEOPALMHINDI14K240.TTF");
    PdfFontFactory.Register(HFOnt, "HindiFont1");
    PdfFont myHindiFont1 = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("HindiFont1", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
    
    PdfFontFactory.Register(HFOnt2, "HindiFont2");
    PdfFont myHindiFont2 = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("HindiFont2", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
    

    //Create Writer
    
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {

        File.Delete(path);

    }
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(path);




    //Create Pdf Document Object
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
   
    //Create A Document
    Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);
    document.SetMargins(90f, 36f, 120f, 36f);

    PdfPage page1 = pdf.AddNewPage();
    document.Add(new iText.Layout.Element.AreaBreak());
    
    //Get Page Size and Canvas
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page1);
    Rectangle pageSize = page1.GetPageSize();

    canvas.BeginText()
      .MoveText(pageSize.GetWidth() / 2-35, pageSize.GetHeight() - 400)
      .SetFontAndSize(myHindiFont1, 9f)
      .ShowText("lfdZy uacj dqvk uacj gS")
      .EndText();
      
     document.Close();
```

I am downloading these fonts from streaming assets to persistent data path using UnityWebRequest.

**I checked for file existence using File.Exists in the persistent data path after disposing Unity Web Requests and it returns true in traces for both font files.**

This is the error I am getting in my device monitor:

> 03-02 13:40:57.084: E/Unity(18347): NotSupportedException: Encoding 1252 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled.
>
> 03-02 13:40:57.084: E/Unity(18347):   at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (System.Int32 codepage) [0x0023f] in <7ba07f088431485bb722f3b3373e87ee>:0
>
> 03-02 13:40:57.084: E/Unity(18347):   at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (System.String name) [0x00012] in <7ba07f088431485bb722f3b3373e87ee>:0
>
> 03-02 13:40:57.084: E/Unity(18347):   at iText.IO.Util.JavaUtil.GetStringForBytes (System.Byte[] bytes, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 length, System.String encoding) [0x00000] in <57da1b8d8a184e278c732544ebe6412a>:0
>
> 03-02 13:40:57.084: E/Unity(18347):   at iText.IO.Util.JavaUtil.GetStringForBytes (System.Byte[] bytes, System.String encoding) [0x00000] in <57da1b8d8a184e278c732544ebe6412a>:0
>
> 03-02 13:40:57.084: E/Unity(18347):   at iText.IO.Source.RandomAccessFileOrArray.ReadString (System.Int32 length, System.String encoding) [0x0000e] in <57da1b8d8a184e278c732544ebe6412a>:0
>
> 03-02 13:40:57.084: E/Unity(18347):   at iText.IO.Font.OpenTypeParser.ReadStandardString (System.Int32 length) [0x00000] in <57da1b8d8a184e278c732544ebe6412a>:0
>
> 03-02 13:40:57.084: E/Unity(18347):   at iText.IO.Font.OpenTypeParser.Process () [0x00

Is there anyone who can look into this help me register fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply saved i18n.dll file in my project and it works. Thanks to all the previous threads.